# Managing the SP Gatherer's temp files in 2013

Tags: 2013, search

howto configure this

http://blogs.technet.com/b/searchguys/archive/2012/09/18/managing-the-sp-gatherer-s-temp-files.aspx

in SharePoint 2013? We have to crawl large file shares. If we do so we're running out of disk space. Have we to configure the Search Service Application anyhow?

Any Suggestion appreciated.

---

Update 2013/12/08
This should be a hint:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chandru/archive/2013/08/15/analytics-component-disk-location-in-sp2013.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be stored in the registry under 'HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Office Server\14.0\Search\Global\Gathering Manager' in TempPath on each server. I see several articles mention that it is the same location as the index, but in my case it is not.

I don't see a way to change it through the SSA as you could in 2010. Though with PowerShell you could write a script to make the change on each server.

Comment: To change the tempPath (or GathererDataPath) is useless because it is reset by the server if
a crawler starts or the server restarts sharepoint

Answer (score -1):

According to this

http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Move-SharePoint-2013-242869e2

a possible solution seems to be to move the indexlocation by a powershell script:

## -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

## Name:               Move-SPEnterpriseSearchIndex.ps1

## Description:         This script will move the SharePoint 2013 Search Index

## Usage:            Run the function with the 3 required Parameters

## By:                 Ivan Josipovic, Softlanding.ca

## -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
function Move-SPEnterpriseSearchIndex($SearchServiceName,$Server,$IndexLocation){ 
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ea 0; 
#Gets the Search Service Application 
$SSA = Get-SPServiceApplication -Name $SearchServiceName; 
if (!$?){throw "Cant find a Search Service Application: `"$SearchServiceName`"";} 
#Gets the Search Service Instance on the Specified Server 
$Instance = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceInstance -Identity $Server; 
if (!$?){throw "Cant find a Search Service Instance on Server: `"$Server`"";} 
#Gets the current Search Topology 
$Current = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchTopology -SearchApplication $SSA -Active; 
if (!$?){throw "There is no Active Topology, you can try removing the `"-Active`" from the line above in the script";} 
#Creates a Copy of the current Search Topology 
$Clone = New-SPEnterpriseSearchTopology -Clone -SearchApplication $SSA -SearchTopology $Current; 
#Adds a new Index Component with the new Index Location 
New-SPEnterpriseSearchIndexComponent -SearchTopology $Clone -IndexPartition 0 -SearchServiceInstance $Instance -RootDirectory $IndexLocation | Out-Null; 
if (!$?){throw "Make sure that Index Location `"$IndexLocation`" exists on Server: `"$Server`"";} 
#Sets our new Search Topology as Active 
Set-SPEnterpriseSearchTopology -Identity $Clone; 
#Removes the old Search Topology 
Remove-SPEnterpriseSearchTopology -Identity $Current -Confirm:$false; 
#Now we need to remove the extra Index Component 
#Gets the Search Topology 
$Current = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchTopology -SearchApplication $SSA -Active; 
#Creates a copy of the current Search Topology 
$Clone=New-SPEnterpriseSearchTopology -Clone -SearchApplication $SSA -SearchTopology $Current; 
#Removes the old Index Component from the Search Topology 
Get-SPEnterpriseSearchComponent -SearchTopology $Clone | ? {($_.GetType().Name -eq "IndexComponent") -and ($_.ServerName -eq $($Instance.Server.Address)) -and ($_.RootDirectory -ne $IndexLocation)} | Remove-SPEnterpriseSearchComponent -SearchTopology $Clone -Confirm:$false; 
#Sets our new Search Topology as Active 
Set-SPEnterpriseSearchTopology -Identity $Clone; 
#Removes the old Search Topology 
Remove-SPEnterpriseSearchTopology -Identity $Current -Confirm:$False; 
Write-Host "The Index has been moved to $IndexLocation on $Server" 
Write-Host "This will not remove the data from the old index location. You will have to do that manually :)"
```

}
Move-SPEnterpriseSearchIndex -SearchServiceName "Search Service Application" -Server "SP2013-WFE" -IndexLocation "C:\Index"

Comment: Hi! Please do not only leave a link as an answer, if the link breaks your answer will be of little help to future readers.